# leetcode 109 : Convert Sorted List to Binary Search Tree

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
public TreeNode sortedListToBST(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null)
        return null;
    if (head.next == null)
        return new TreeNode (head.val);
    ListNode slow = head;
    ListNode fast = head;
    ListNode pre = null;
    ListNode mid = null;
    while (fast.next != null && fast != null){
        pre = slow;
        fast = fast.next.next;
        slow = slow.next;
    }
    mid = slow;
    pre.next = null;
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(slow.val);
    root.right = sortedListToBST(mid.next);
    root.left = sortedListToBST(head);

    return root;
}
```

}

This is my solution but it shows:
java.lang.NullPointerException

when i change 
`while (fast.next != null && fast != null){`
to
`while (fast != null && fast.next != null){`
the solution is accepted

i don't know the differences between them.

Comment: `while (fast.next != null && fast != null){` will cause **NullPointerException** when `fast` is null,that's the reason

Comment: when you check two conditions with &&, the following rule applies:
If the first check results in false, the second (or all other) condition(s) won't be checked anymore.

Comment: @Ole VV,I am typing the answer and found you close it,oh no

Comment: @OleV.V. What I want to say is that I lost a chance to earn reputation,nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is how `&&` operator works... if there is a condition (cond1 && cond2), compiler will check if cond1 is true.. if it is false it wont check for second condition.. it will check for 2nd condition only if 1st one is true.. in your case.. if fast is null.. fast.next will give null pointer... so you should always check if fast is null before checking fast.next...

Comment: The questions is closed,why do you still can add an answer to it? I can not do it now

Comment: @lucumt haha, i think i added it just before closing it... i cannot add an answer now as well

Comment: I was wondering too. As of writing the question stands as closed 10 mins ago and answered 7 mins ago.

Comment: @OleV.V. Seems like consistency issues with database :P maybe we can add one more question on stackoverflow to discuss this :D

Comment: Thank you!  i neglect it